# angularjs variable in template like JSTL in JSP

Tags: angularjs

**JSP (Using JSTL)**

```
<c:set var="total" value="0"></c:set>
<c:set var="total" value="${total + stu.score}"><c:set>
${total}
```

The code is the code that takes the values ​​from the DB and calculates the sum of the students' scores in the JSP. I want to code in the angularjs template as above.
 I tried ng-init but it does not work as expected. Is there a solution?

Comment: your question is not clear.. can you explain more.
Also you can not use ng-init for a variable which will change. ng-init variable can not be modified and have multiple restriction. You porbably could initialize the variable in controller and then add/ substract from that

Comment: I will try to do it on the controller and if it does not work, I will be able to ask again as detailed explanation. Thank you for answering the unclear question. As a beginner, I get a way.